# ftp giving the file "644" and permission denied when I try to change it

Tags: python, unix, ftp

im moving a file with ftp to a unix machine and it is assigning it "644" permissions when I want "777" so that it is writable. I also cant change it, I get permission denied.

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(ip, login, pw)

with open(fName, "rb") as f:
   ftp.cwd(fPath)
   ftp.storlines("STOR " + fName, f)
   ftp.sendcmd("SITE CHMOD 777 " + fName)
```

Comment: using root login?

Comment: no, will that do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, use the root login. I had a similar problem and was using filezilla to fix it locally, until I realized filezilla was using the root login and I was using an engineers. This is probably answered elsewhere.